# ShellCommandActivity and python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to use Elastic Data Pipeline with a shell command activity to process some data files. Specifically I'm trying to use python to process some staged data.

My first attempt at the python script looked like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

print "We've entered the python file"
print os.curdir
print os.listdir(os.curdir)
print ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR}
```

This code threw an error when the fourth print statement was hit because ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR} was undefined.

After that I tried passing ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR} as an argument to the script and modified the script to look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

print "We've entered the python file"
print os.curdir
print os.listdir(os.curdir)
print sys.argv
```

This time the script successfully finished and had the following output.

```
We've entered the python file
.
['taskRunner.zip', 'mysql-connector-java-bin.jar', 'csv-serde.jar', 'run.sh', 'TaskRunner-1.0.jar', 'pipeline-serde.jar', 'run.out', 'output']
['/mnt/taskRunner/output/tmp/ActivityIdQC6BK20140722T170548Attempt1_command.sh', '${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR}']
```

Again, the ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR} was not "substituted" for anything resembling the file I was staging. Is what I'm trying to do possible? If not, is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out ${INPUT1_STAGING_DIR} is set as an environment variable and can be accessed as such. The following script works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

print "We've entered the python file"

print os.curdir
print os.listdir(os.curdir)

inputDir = os.getenv('INPUT1_STAGING_DIR')
print inputDir
print os.path.isfile(inputDir)
print os.path.isdir(inputDir)
print os.listdir(inputDir)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. os.getenv('INPUT1_STAGING_DIR') returns None.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Stage = true. This option is provided as a dropdown field in the ShellCommandActivity activity.

Specifically quoting the documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-staging.html

Staging data locally on a resource
The input data automatically copies into the resource local file system. Output data automatically copies from the resource local file system to the output data node. For example, when you configure ShellCommandActivity inputs and outputs with staging = true, the input data is available as INPUTx_STAGING_DIR and output data is available as OUTPUTx_STAGING_DIR, where x is the number of input or output.

Hope this solves your original issue.